# What’s wrong with this pressure washer nozzle?

Tags: water, pressure-washer

I just got this Husqvarna pressure washer and used it to clean my back patio. I moved it to the front to do the driveway, and now it is spraying out of the sides of the quick-disconnect nozzle joint. Not very high pressure at all!
[image: water spraying from inside the nozzle joint]

I noticed there is a broken ring around the quick-disconnect, but can’t remember if that was broken before, like a split washer, maybe.
[image: a brass manifold with ball bearings and a possible split washer]

The other tip has the same problem, so I’m pretty sure it’s an issue with the quick-disconnect on the wand, not with the tips.

What did I break or lose?

Comment: there should be a rubber seal

Comment: You probably don't have the tip fully seated in the QDC (Quick DisConnect) fitting of the wand.

Comment: Pretty sure that ring it just to keep the part you pull back (which is spring-loaded) from popping off the end.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's an o-ring *inside* the quick coupler, that's cut/damaged or missing and needs to be replaced.

Also check all the nozzles/tips for damage on the machined surface that goes into the quick coupler.  Any nick or dent will cut the o-ring or cause a leak.

Comment: Yeah, there’s no O-ring in there at all. I called Husqvarna and they sent me a new one.

Answer (score 11):

That ring is not broken. it's a lock ring that keeps the slip fitting from falling off. Pull the slip fitting down and insert your pressure tip and push it down hard and release the slip fitting to lock the tip in place. Make sure the presure tip is clean and not blocked.

If that doesn't fix it, get a flashlite and look inside the quick disconnect for an "o" ring. It could be cracked, chipped or missing.

Comment: Thanks. Both pressure tips are clean: plenty of water flows through them, and they are brand new.  I tried pushing them into the concrete to see if I wasn’t pushing hard enough with my hands, but that didn’t fix it either.

Comment: If that ring didn't have that split, it would be impossible to install.